# Проблема с получением ROM

Tags: android

Требуется получить ROM память девайса. делаю так:

```
    this.romTotal = phone_storage_total();
    this.romAvail = phone_storage_free();
    this.romTotal >>= 10;
    this.romAvail >>= 10;

public static long phone_storage_free(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getAvailableBlocks() * stat.getBlockSize(); 
    return free_memory;
}

public static long phone_storage_total(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long free_memory = stat.getBlockCount() * stat.getBlockSize();
    return free_memory;
}
```

На выходе:
romTotal -1578 неверно
romAvail 1737 верно

Почему romTotal отрицательный? Как получить правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас переполнение `int`'а. Надо так:

```
long free_memory = ((long )stat.getBlockCount()) * ((long ))stat.getBlockSize());
```